# Android Volley: Response.ErrorListener() returning 'null' error

Tags: php, android, android-volley, androidhttpclient

On StringRequest, Response.ErrorListener() giver null error.

In log it shows:

E/Login_1_Phone: Posting params: {mobile=8681070970}

E/Volley: [7239] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://54.254.177.58/android_sms/msg91/request_sms.php

E/Login_1_Phone: Error: null

Source Code:

Activity requesting:

```
package com.iotaconcepts.dr;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.iotaconcepts.dr.R;
import com.iotaconcepts.dr.app.Config;
import com.iotaconcepts.dr.app.MyApplication;    
import com.iotaconcepts.dr.Utils.SharedPreference;
import com.iotaconcepts.dr.service.HttpService;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by prasang on 29/1/16.
 */
public class Login_1_Phone extends Activity{

Button ok;
EditText et_phone;
String phoneNumber;
private static String TAG = Login_1_Phone.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_1_phone);

    init();

    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            phoneNumber = et_phone.getText().toString();
            if (phoneNumber.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(Login_1_Phone.this, "Please enter mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                Intent i = new Intent(Login_1_Phone.this, Login_2_OTP.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else if (phoneNumber.length() != 10 ) {
                Toast.makeText(Login_1_Phone.this, "Please enter a valid mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (phoneNumber.length() == 10) {

                //TODO: API Here

                requestForSMS(phoneNumber);



            }
        }
    });
}

private void init()
{
    et_phone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_login_phone_number);
    ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_login_phone_ok);
}


private void requestForSMS (final String mobile) {

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Config.URL_REQUEST_SMS, new Response.Listener<String>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(response);

                // Parsing json object response
                // response will be a json object
                boolean error = responseObj.getBoolean("error");
                String message = responseObj.getString("message");

                // checking for error, if not error SMS is initiated
                // device should receive it shortly
                if (!error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent i = new Intent(Login_1_Phone.this, Login_2_OTP.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                // hiding the progress bar
                //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onErrorResponse: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }) {

        /**
         * Passing user parameters to our server
         * @return
         */
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("mobile", mobile);

            Log.e(TAG, "Posting params: " + params.toString());

            return params;
        }

    };

    strReq.setShouldCache(false);

    // Adding request to request queue
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
}


}
```

HttpService Class

```
package com.iotaconcepts.dr.service;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.iotaconcepts.dr.MainActivity;
import com.iotaconcepts.dr.app.Config;
import com.iotaconcepts.dr.app.MyApplication;
import com.iotaconcepts.dr.Utils.SharedPreference;

public class HttpService extends IntentService {

private static String TAG = HttpService.class.getSimpleName();

public HttpService() {
    super(HttpService.class.getSimpleName());
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        String otp = intent.getStringExtra("otp");
        verifyOtp(otp);
    }
}

/**
 * Posting the OTP to server and activating the user
 * @param otp otp received in the SMS
 */

private void verifyOtp(final String otp) {

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.URL_VERIFY_OTP, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {

                JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(response);

                // Parsing json object response
                // response will be a json object
                boolean error = responseObj.getBoolean("error");
                String message = responseObj.getString("message");

                if (!error) {
                    // parsing the user profile information
                    JSONObject profileObj = responseObj.getJSONObject("profile");

                    String name = profileObj.getString("name");
                    String email = profileObj.getString("email");
                    String mobile = profileObj.getString("mobile");

                    //PrefManager pref = new PrefManager(getApplicationContext());
                    //pref.createLogin(name, email, mobile);

                    // User verified! Go to main activity now.
                    Intent intent = new Intent(HttpService.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("otp", otp);

            Log.e(TAG, "Posting params: " + params.toString());
            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
}

}
```

Comment: have you tried the MSG91 new service SENDOTP with their own android library : https://github.com/SendOTP/SendOTPAndroid

Comment: "response code 404" means the url is wrong.. Please check your url...

Comment: Looks like you just need to drop `msg91/` from the URL.